# Submenu behind section

Tags: css, wordpress

I have wordpress site (Let's see" [Here is a link](http://przedszkole.pwoj.pl/)) but I don't know why when I put my mouse over the "kontakt" in nav I can't see the sub-menu.
What's wrong with syntax? It's Wordpress so I can't give you a code - it would be too much.

Comment: Please create the issue using something like jsFiddle so it's reproducible in the future. You most certainly can pull out the relevant HTML & CSS to show the problem - it being in WordPress doesn't affect that.

Comment: Not "let's see", let's read: [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You need remove `overflow:hidden` on the `.sec--head` element